How to draw a background image behind (sub)section titles?
How would I go about drawing an image behind the text of (sub, sub)section titles? I looked into various packages (e.g. background, tikz, tcolorbox), but every time got lost in overly complicated examples, that did something just slightly different.
I expect any of those packages be able to do it, and I'd be happy with a solution using any of those, at this point o_O
Here is a simple example that comes as close to what I want as I could make it, without knowing too much about either of the packages:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}

% document type
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{balance}

%-----------[ section title background ]

\usepackage{tikz}

%---------------------------[ document ]

\begin{document}

% section title
\twocolumn[\section*{%
    \centering%
    \tikz[blend mode=multiply]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{section_header.png}}%
    SECTION TITLE}]
\balance

\par\lipsum[1]

% subsection no.1
\subsection*{%
    \centering%
    \tikz[blend mode=multiply]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{section_header.png}}%
    SUBSECTION%
}
\par\lipsum[1]

% subsection no.2
\subsection*{%
    \centering%
    \tikz[blend mode=multiply]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{section_header.png}}%
    SUBSECTION%
}
\par\lipsum[1]

% subsection no.3
\subsection*{%
    \centering%
    \tikz[blend mode=multiply]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{section_header.png}}%
    SUBSECTION%
}
\par\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

Which produces a page like this:

When I was hoping for something as seen in the image below, where the background image behind the section titles stretches properly across the \textwidth/\columnwidth, and the section-title itself is centered horizontally and vertically of the background image (indicated in red), instead:

I suspect this is pretty easy to do, if you understand the node/anchor/etc. systems behind these libraries, but I couldn't find a reference to anchor images to section titles (and adding it directly to the \section macro, obviously doesn't work like I tried).
NOTE: I also found this answer, which seems to get fairly close, but I couldn't find how to fill the \tcolorbox with an image.
If you want to copy/paste the above example, please feel free to grab the section_header.png image here as well, to easily reproduce the example:


You can't just place \includegraphics inside a \tikz command directly. You need to place it inside a \node. And you should not put such things inside a \section command. Have a look at the titlesec package which allows you to style (sub*)section titles. Since the text of your titles is black, do you need blend mode=multiply at all? I would probably not use TikZ here, but just place the image in a box with zero width or height/depth.

I would suggest a combination of the titlesec and the multicols package. When placing a \section command in the optional command of the default \twocolumn command, the spacing after the first paragraph might be a bit off.
Some notes:

I would not use TikZ here. The text is black and nothing is transparent, so I fail to see the need for a blend mode option. Also, you can just use a zero-sized box to place the image behind the text. If you still want to use TikZ, note that you should always place things inside \nodes.
You should be careful with placing arbitrary code as argument to the \section command (same holds for related commands such as \subsection) as the section title might also be used internally by other mechanisms and the additional code is likely to break this. It is better to make use of a package such as titlesec for styling.
The multicol package balances columns per default, so you don't need to use the balance package.
There is no need to use \par commands everywhere in your code. Actually, you should use this only when really needed.

A minimal working example would be:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}

% document type
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\Large}{}{0pt}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \raisebox{-8pt}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{section_header.png}%
        }%
    }%
    \hfill #1 \hfill%
}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \raisebox{-2pt}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{section_header.png}%
        }%
    }%
    \hfill #1 \hfill%
}

%---------------------------[ document ]

\begin{document}

% section title
\section{SECTION TITLE}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent\lipsum[1]
    
    % subsection no.1
    \subsection{SUBSECTION}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    % subsection no.2
    \subsection{SUBSECTION}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    % subsection no.3
    \subsection{SUBSECTION}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}



Ooh, that looks great, I'm so happy to see a working example! Now I just have to adapt it in my own code, thank you! Some notes: (a) I used \twocolumn since that seems to make it easier to integrate column-wide floats/images, compared to \multicols (I'm using both throughout the whole thing, depending on where what kind of images should be placed). (b) I totally agree, my example, with the mushed-in image in the \section is pretty atrocious -- after I while I just wanted anything to work without having to dig through the 400+ pages tikz manual @_@

Scaling a picture of a frame whose edges are broken/abraded seems not a good approach: If you do preserve the aspect ratio (height:width) of the frame picture, then material of too much vertical height does not fit into the frame. If you do not preserve the aspect ratio of the picture, then it is not ensured at all that within a frame the width of vertical edges is always the same as the height of horizontal edges. Also widths/heights of edges of different frames might differ.
Be that as it may.
Probably the following does the trick:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}

% document type
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%----------[ stuff for measuring boxes ]
\newbox\scratchboxA
\newbox\scratchboxB
\NewDocumentCommand\MyThingie{mmm}{%
  \begingroup
  \centering
  \vbox{#3}%
  \setbox\scratchboxA=\lastbox
  \vbox{\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}}%
  \setbox\scratchboxB=\lastbox
  \rlap{%
    \copy\scratchboxB
  }%
  \lower
  -.5\dimexpr
     \ht\scratchboxB+\dp\scratchboxB-\ht\scratchboxA+\dp\scratchboxA
  \relax
  \box\scratchboxA
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\MyThingie=\MyThirdOfThree}%
\newcommand\MySavedThingie{}%
\let\MySavedThingie=\MyThingie
\newcommand\MyThirdOfThree[3]{#3}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\MyThingie=\string\MyThirdOfThree}%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\MyThingie=\string\MySavedThingie}%
}%

%---------------------------[ document ]

\hyphenation{con-sec-te-tu-er mag-na}

\begin{document}

\sloppy

% section title
\twocolumn[\section*{\MyThingie{section_header.png}{\textwidth}{SECTION TITLE}}]%
\balance
\par\lipsum[1]
\bigskip

% subsection no.1
\subsection*{\MyThingie{section_header.png}{\columnwidth}{SUBSECTION}}
\par\lipsum[1]

% subsection no.2
\subsection*{\MyThingie{section_header.png}{\columnwidth}{SUBSECTION}}
\par\lipsum[1]

% subsection no.3
\subsection*{\MyThingie{section_header.png}{\columnwidth}{SUBSECTION}}
\par\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


The \pdfstringDisableCommands-thingie is in case \MyThingie goes into a moving argument which also makes it into pdf-bookmarks where only the string denoting the title of the section or subsection is needed.
But you should stick to Jasper Habicht's approach because it also handles the case of the moving argument making it into a page header (which, however, is unlikely for starred sectioning commands).

This looks pretty fantastic, thank you! I understand your code significantly less than the solution proposed above, so this will take some time to digest, but if I can find the time, I will try out both alternatives, and see how they work out! Would you maybe mind telling me what the \pdfstringdefDisableCommands part does? Is it to automatically generate a ToC entry for the section titles..?
